# Mobile redirect of .NET site - how to setup in IIRF?

Tags: .net, .htaccess, redirect, mobile, iirf

I am working on a .NET based mobile site (m.website.com).
I am using IIRF on the main site (non-mobile) for URL rewriting.

Now, it is required to redirect any mobile user to the mobile site if they land up on the main site (www.website.com). I am able to achieve this by checking the user agent in IIRF and redirecting.

**The issue I'm facing is that:**

The mobile site will have a link back to the main site. If a mobile user clicks on this link then he should not be redirected back to the mobile device.

I tried to follow the htaccess solution mentioned in this post - [Mobile Redirect using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess) but its not working properly with IIRF. `RewriteCond` for `{QueryString}` is not working properly. Also, I am not sure if I can set a cookie from IIRF itself, the way its mentioned in the link.

I have been struggling with this issue for quite a few hours, it would be great if someone could help.

Another approach I tried was checking the `HTTP_REFERER` to avoid redirection if the referring site is the mobile site but that did not work as well.

Comment: Response awaited. Still seeking for answers. Thank you @sjwarner for the edit. How can this question be promoted further to get noticed?

Answer (score 0):

[IIRF does not offer the `[co]` modifier to set a cookie](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/Iirf21Help/html/a8988008-feb2-4a91-9abc-03043ba308fe.htm#Options) - but you should be able to do that easily from within .NET.

IIRF however supports checking for cookie values by using `{HTTP_COOKIE}` in your conditions.

[`{QUERY_STRING}` is also supported](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/Iirf21Help/html/bdaf0dbe-e539-4bf5-9231-1dae3b0e27a5.htm#ServerVars) (just make sure to include the underscore). Also,  it's `HTTP_REFERER`, not `HTTP_REFERRER` ([a misspelling we'll have to live with...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer#Origin_of_the_term_referer)).

You could therefore adapt the rewrite rules based on the user agent *(where does that list come from??)* [from the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess). Redirect to the mobile site if:

- the url asked for is not already the mobile site
- the url does not contain the *no-redirect* querystring (`?noredirect=1` or similar)
- the *no-redirect cookie* is *not* present
- the user agent matches the magic long list from the linked question

Comment: I've just seen that `HTTP_REFERER` has wrongly been edited... What did not work well with IIRF and `HTTP_REFERER` ?