# accessing different directory if mobile browser detected

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have developed two sites.
one is for normal web browsers and another is for mobile browsers.
now what I need to do is, if some one is accessing my site from mobile with URL

`www.xyz.com/PQR&page=search`

then user should have the result of below URL

`www.xyz.com/folder1/some/parameter/PQR`

How can I do this with .htaccess.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess

Comment: yes. I have seen that. but it seems a different case. my concern is how to access a PQR parameter after adding some extra parameters like `folder1/folder2/PQR`

Answer (score 0):

You Can USe the mod_rewrtite in htaccess for this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /

RewriteRule /PQR&page=search /folder1/some/parameter/PQR
</IfModule>
```