# Mobile redirect with .htaccess for www.example.com OR example.com

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mobile

I'm going to be starting on a mobile version of my website soon, already have space set up for it as follows:

http://mobile.example.com/

I found a solution here:
[Best way to redirect mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421577/best-way-to-redirect-mobile-devices)

^ This seems to work just fine except when I try this from my iphone4 it will only redirect if I enter the www in the url.. if I leave it out I just get my regular site.

So I need the mobile redirect to work if the user enters www.example.com OR example.com

I made some modifications to the code and got it almost working.  Now it works for both versions of the url but I have to refresh once to get the mobile site. Obviously I want the redirect to work when they first hit the site.  I'm sure I'm missing something here, let me know what you think. I have aplus.net as my host btw.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.example\.com|example\.com) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mobile.example.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

Reponse to Jon Lin...

Yes there are a few other rules in my .htaccess

Defining different index page types:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm INDEX.HTML INDEX.HTM Index.html Index.htm default.htm Default.htm index.shtml index.cgi index.php index.php3 index.jsp index.phtml
```

Removing .php extension from urls

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Then this here which was put in automatically from the cp:

```
# [ CP Global Redirection - Start ]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !^www\..*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !^www\..*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R]
</IfModule>
# [ CP Global Redirection - End ]
```

Comment: Are there any other rewrite rules or redirects setup in your server/vhost config or htaccess?

Comment: Apparently I'm not familiar with responding to comments on here.

I tried to paste in the other rules from my .htaccess but looks like it was too many characters?

Comment: Edit your post and add them to the bottom

Comment: I suggest you use Javascript based redirection which is more robust than user agent guessing: https://github.com/miohtama/detectmobile.js

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Mobile redirect code we use on our Aplus.net platform for our mobile application. Should be able to use this to redirect to your own custom site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-WAP-PROFILE} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:PROFILE} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(Alcatel|Asus|Android|BlackBerry|Ericsson|Fly|Huawei|i-mate|iPAQ|iPhone|iPod|LG-|LGE-|MDS_|MOT-|Nokia|Palm|Panasonic|Pantech|Philips|Sagem|Samsung|Sharp|SIE-|Symbian|Vodafone|Voxtel|WebOS|Windows\s+CE|ZTE-|Zune).*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/vnd.wap.xhtml\+xml [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/vnd.wap.wml [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://mobile.%1/ [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-WAP-PROFILE} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:PROFILE} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(Alcatel|Asus|Android|BlackBerry|Ericsson|Fly|Huawei|i-mate|iPAQ|iPhone|iPod|LG-|LGE-|MDS_|MOT-|Nokia|Palm|Panasonic|Pantech|Philips|Sagem|Samsung|Sharp|SIE-|Symbian|Vodafone|Voxtel|WebOS|Windows\s+CE|ZTE-|Zune).*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/vnd.wap.xhtml\+xml [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/vnd.wap.wml [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://mobile.%{HTTP_HOST}/ [L]
```

Comment: Hey David, thank you so much!

This works like a charm, now to get to work on a mobile site.