# Rewrite rule in htaccess for mobile version

Tags: php, .htaccess, mobile

I am using codeigniter framework for my site and I have  done two site one for accessing through mobile and another for accessing through pcs.  both are in same domain . My site url is like this `http://mydomain.com`And my mobile is `http://mydomain.com/celphone`. I need to write htaccess rule which redirect to site url `http://mydomain.com/celphone` when i am accessing site from mobile and i need to rewrite to `http://mydomain.com/` when i am accessing the site from pc.

How can i write rewrite rule in such case ,please help any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>As [scessor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9849863/295264), said, it cannot be done with `.htaccess`.</strike> You need to analyse the browser's user agent for this.

Check out [this](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/) mobile detection in php.

Usage is as easy as this

```
if ($detect->isMobile()) {
    header("location: mobile.yourdomain.com");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: This answer is plain wrong, detecting mobile browsers in a .htaccess is absolutely possible. It will probably also be faster, as the request will be redirected before it even reaches the PHP engine. See scessor's answer for a link to a working .htaccess solution.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The `.htaccess` has no information about the device, so it can't recognize the difference. You have to do this with your source code.</strike> (see my update below)

E.g. in javascript analyze the browsers `userAgent` and redirect by setting `window.location`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[  
    var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));  
    if (mobile) {  
        window.location = "http://www.yoursite.com/mobile.html";  
    }  
// ]]></script>
```

=== UPDATE ===

Read the anwers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess) to see how you can redirect in the `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it with PHP or any other server side language, you can look for the user agent and determine where to redirect the user. You might also find a ready-made class to do the checking for you. I've always used this and worked like a charm http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/