# I want to make dropdown menu show only in mobile view

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I made a dropdown menu, but now I want this menu to only show in mobile view, and not in other views. I guess it's done using "visible-xs" or something like that, but I couldn't code it.

Here's my HTML,

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Food, LLC</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-nav" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapsable-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Chicken</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Beef</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sushi</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Use media query. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying div only on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300415/displaying-div-only-on-mobile-devices)

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display#hiding-elements

Answer (score 0):

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Food, LLC</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-nav" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapsable-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse visible-xs">
      <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
        <li><a href="#">Chicken</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Beef</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sushi</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```