# META Tags redirect when detect Chrome browser

Tags: html, asp.net, google-chrome, redirect, meta-tags

Any idea to do, when it detect Chrome browser and it will be redirect to another page?
i use this (sample alert) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).ready(function(){

/* Get browser */
$.browser.chrome = /chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

/* Detect Chrome */
if($.browser.chrome){
/* Do something for Chrome at this point */
alert("If you not able to view this app on chrome, please use FIREFOX or IE browser. Thank you.");
}

});
</script>
```

But it seem just working on HTML (i have two file, i need this for asp.net/VBScript)

Comment: What do you mean, "just working on HTML (i have two file, i need this for asp.net/VBScript)"? Asp documents are HTML too. (By the way, VBScript is for classic ASP. ASP.NET has VB.Net.) Also, don't do browser detection; do feature detection. What happens if someone visits your site with Safari or Konqueror?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I would highly suggest using .htaccess to handle this. Here is an example of how your file should look:

> RewriteEngine on
>   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Chrome
>   RewriteRule .* http://site.example.com/ [R]

This may be of help as well: [.htaccess Redirect to specific webpage based on browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057575/htaccess-redirect-to-specific-webpage-based-on-browser)