# Using .htaccess to redirect obsolete browsers (HELP)

Tags: firefox, redirect, opera

How i can do this, opera and firefox visitors automatically redirect on my subdomain? Example my domain is www.site.com  i want when visitor come to my website with opera and firefox, automatically redirect on www.sub.site.com

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess Redirect to specific webpage based on browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057575/htaccess-redirect-to-specific-webpage-based-on-browser)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a http_user_agent based redirection using htaccess.

Try the following code in Root/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mainsite.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (opera|firebox) [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.site.com/$1 [NC,L,R]
```

This will redirect **opera** or **firebox** user_agents from mainsite to subdomain.

Comment: actually (opera|firefox)