# .htaccess allow only from Chrome, Opera, Mozilla, Safari, redirect from others

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting, user-agent

I want to configure redirect if the user doesn't use Chrome, Safari, Opera or Mozilla.

For inverse problem (if I don't want Chrome etc.) there is a solution:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Chrome
RewriteRule ^abcd.html$ chrome.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Safari
RewriteRule ^abcd.html$ safari.html [NC,L]
```

Adding `!` before doesn't work

Comment: A `!` prefix means `no`. This should work: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Chrome` then add `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Safari` etc. May I ask why you want to do this, though?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check now. To block IE and other weird browsers, where my system may fail

Comment: You know that the User-Agent string can be spoofed, right? What's the real reason to do this? Sounds like an X-Y problem.

Comment: What you want is usually done with a bit of JavaScript on the client side -- you can detect the browser type much more reliably in the browser itself.

Comment: You could consider displaying a message in the browsers your site doesn’t work well with. You can target older versions of IE with conditional comments, for example: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html or use JS as @mustaccio says

Comment: Yes, I do now in this way, but .htaccess does it quicker

Comment: @Pekka웃, !Chrome doesn't work

Comment: Try with the `[NC]` flag.

Comment: Good! Thanks. Answer the question in Answer form, I'll mark it as correct. By the way, explain why it worked

Comment: May I somehow write several files to redirect in RewriteRule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negation is done using the `!` operator. Using the `[NC]` flag will also discard strings like `chrome`, `chRome` etc:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Chrome [NC]
RewriteRule ^abcd.html$ chrome.html [NC,L]
```