# Using proxypass and proxypassreverse

Tags: linux, apache, redirect, proxy, proxypass

I've got a problem using ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse. Read already a lot of things, but can't get my head around things.

We need to make a connection between our webserver and an application using the server location. Connecting to the webserver through webbrowser, there isn't any problem.

- Using domain.com in a webbrowser redirects to domain.com/path/index.html . This is correct and impossible to change.
- Using domain.com in the app gives an error, because server location is not found. This happens because the server is located at the url domain.com/path/

I am trying to figure out how to change the configuration on my webserver using Virtualhosts and ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse, because I guess that's the best way to change the url. I don't want to manually put domain.com/path/ into my app, because it affects many users ... Not really into asking all of them to change the URL ...

Comment: "*server location is not found*", what does that mean?  The DNS resolution does not work?  If you ask for domain.com in a browser and you are redirected (I guess a 301 or 302 redirect), does your application support redirection requests?  If not, then configure your application to go directly to the specific path you want or expect.  Why would changing the application affect users?  Do you not control your code?  If you want a different redirect between the browser and the application, you will need to use the client agent.

Comment: The exact translation to English (from dutch) is more like "Cannot address the server location". So DNS resolution is not an issue, using a browser works fine.
The application is indeed not our own, but it needs a connection to our webserver. It would affect users because right now their connection is domain.com, but due to a change from Windows Server to a Linux, this has now changed.

Comment: Got it.  Look at what the user agent for your application.  You can then perform a redirection specific to that agent.  Ex. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057575/htaccess-redirect-to-specific-webpage-based-on-browser.  This will allow you to redirect differently based on browser or application.