# htaccess redirect if trying to access the homepage only

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mobile

I used the method described at: [Mobile Redirect using htaccess to redirect mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess). Works great.

Now, what my client is trying to do is if someone is on mobile, if they are trying to access that is not the homepage, then they do NOT get redirected. So, if they ARE opening the homepage, the redirect works as normal. If, for example, they are opening anything else such as the blog, it does not redirect to the mobile site. So, the only time they get redirected is if they are trying to access the homepage.

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: I don't know how else to word it. What lines of code would I enter in the .htaccess perform the redirect **only** if the target is the homepage?

Comment: What lines of code would I enter in the .htaccess perform the redirect only if the target is the homepage?