# Mobile redirection using .htaccess - only on homepage

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mobile, request, uri

I started by using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess) in order to create a Mobile redirect, and it works perfectly.

What I need to do next, however, is prevent it from happening on any page other than the homepage. In other words: If the user loads the homepage from a mobile device, the redirect should happen - but if they load any other page from a mobile device, the redirect should not occur.

Example:

---

homepage URL = redirect

---

blog URL = NO-redirect

about us URL = NO-redirect

etc etc etc

---

Here is the code that I have currently:

```
# Check if this is the noredirect query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=0(&|$)
# Set a cookie, and skip the next rule
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:0:www.domain.com]

# Failed attempt at redirecting only homepage
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^(domain\.com|www\.domain\.com)$ [NC]
# Check if we're just going to the homepage - fail
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index.php)?$ 

RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  "maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !macintosh [NC]

# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.

# Can not read and write cookie in same request, must duplicate condition
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)m=0(&|$) 

# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}        !^.*mredir=0.*$ [NC]

# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ http://m.domain.com [R,L]
```

And that didn't work. What do I do?

Comment: Your problem is probably related to using [OR].  It's not clear the rules you are using from the linked SO answer.  Please include all the rewrite rules.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I edited the post to show my current code. I took out the [OR] but still no go :(

Comment: @hdwebpros So what you're saying is that the rest of the file is unchanged, you just added the two rows with `index.php` and `/` and it stops redirecting at all?

Comment: Thanks Joachim. I edited the file to Jon Lin's suggestion. It still doesn't work. By that I mean it redirects every web request to the mobile device, even if I'm initially trying to access an interior page (such as the blog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rewrite rules below were tested in an `.htaccess` file in the document root.  Replace `m.domain.com` and `domain.com` as appropriate.

Additionally you can force mobile on or off for any URL by appending `?m=0` or `?m=1`, or setting the `mredir` cookie with the scripting language (php in this case).

```
RewriteEngine On

# Put forced mobile state into 'mredir' cookie
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)m=([0-1])(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:%1:.domain.com]

# Forced mobile? (m=1)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    !^m\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=1(&|$) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}  ^.*mredir=1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)m=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^               http://m.domain.com [R=302,L]

# Forced regular? (m=0)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^m\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=0(&|$) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}  ^.*mredir=0
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)m=1(&|$)
RewriteRule ^               http://domain.com [R=302,L]

# Auto redirect to mobile if not forced above
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)m=0(&|$)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !.*mredir=0
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !macintosh [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile}%{HTTP:Profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-|dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-|maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv|palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany|sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo|teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi|wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-|up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp|symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
# Only auto-redirect on / or /index.php
RewriteRule ^(\/|index\.php)?$ http://m.domain.com [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm sure your answer will be much more beneficial than my stumbled upon (but working) solution

Comment: Also, your solution would not work how you requested if the URL was `/index.php`.   That RewriteCond really did nothing useful anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
```

The request uri cannot be both `/index.php` **AND** `/` at the same time. This regex needs to be combined into an either/or:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index.php)?$
```

Comment: Thanks Jon Lin. I tried your suggestion. It makes sense to me now. It still doesn't redirect though. By that I mean it redirects every web request to the mobile website, even if I'm initially trying to access an interior page (such as the blog)

Comment: @hdwebpros You could alternatively get rid of that condition entirely, and change the rule to: `RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ http://m.domain.com [R,L]`

Comment: Thanks again. Just tried that. Still no go. :( I type in the blog URL (domain.com/blog) and it still redirects me to the m. site

Comment: Do you have any other ideas to why it won't do that?

Answer (score 0):

For some freak reason, for now, this is working?!?!?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/$
```

Why, I have no idea