# RewriteCond to exclude a path not working

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want this URL:

```
http://www.example.com/path/antyhing
```

to NOT be redirected.

Here's what I have which is not working:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://m.example.com/ [R,L]
```

Currently it redirects all URLs to `http://m.example.com/`

Here is the full code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On

# Check if mobile=1 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=1(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# Check if mobile=0 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 0
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# Skip next rule if mobile=0
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]

# Check if this looks like a mobile device
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$

# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie}        !\mobile=0(;|$)
# Don't redirect "path" pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.+?/path/.*$ [NC]
# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^ http://m.example.com/ [R,L]
```

Comment: It should work but you might have other rules conflicting with this rule. Can you post your current code from .htaccess?

Comment: It looks good. Can you try: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/ [NC]` (I believe `path` needs to be changed with actual page name)

Comment: @anubhava Thanks a lot, unfortunately any page under `/path/ ` is still being redirected :(

Comment: A side question, why do you have `\mobile` instead of `mobile`?

Comment: Do you have a `.htaccess` anywhere under `DOCUMENT_ROOT/path` also?

Comment: @anubhava No there is no other `.htaccess` file than the main one at the root.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you replace your last rule with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Check if mobile=1 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=1(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# Check if mobile=0 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 0
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# Skip next rule if mobile=0 [OR] if it's a file [OR] if /path/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$) [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/path/.*$
RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]

# Check if this looks like a mobile device
RewriteCond %{HTTP_PROFILE}       !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}        !mobile=0(;|$)
# Don't redirect "path" pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/path/.*$ [NC]
# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^ http://m.example.com/ [R,L,NC]
```

**Edit by OP:** The only problem was coming from the `%{REQUEST_URI}` that for a reason that I don't understand only works against `^.*/path/.*$`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just did but it still redirect all pages :( What could be wrong?

Comment: It is indeed super strange. Did you test my entire code and it works for you? If yes, then what could wrong in my side? I don't have other `.htaccess` file, could it be browser caching? I'm trying to understand and solve this issue today... Kind of desperate after spending 3 hours trying every possible combination!

Comment: Thank you so much! My Apache version is 2.2.22 running on CentOS 5.8, it's a DV Managed server on MediaTemple, thanks!

Comment: This is to detect User-Agent-Profile in the HTTP request header, which is sent by some Mobile Devices (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UAProf). If it can help, the original code in my `.htaccess` comes from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7081855/2327283

Comment: It's working for you? It doesn't for me!!! Can you post the full code that works for you? I don't understand what I'm doing wrong! :(

Comment: I think there is an error in your code, the 3rd line after "`# Check if this looks like a mobile device`" should not have `[NC,OR]` (remove the `OR`), no?

Comment: I tried your code in a clean empty `.htaccess` file and your code does not work. It does not detect mobile devices correctly (I'm being redirected even from a desktop browser) and /path/mypage/ is also redirected. I'm getting crazy!

Comment: Forget testing from desktop. Just test from mobile device using the regular URL http://www.example.com/ which should redirect to http://m.example.com/ except for http://www.example.com/path/no-redirect/. _By the way you can simulate mobile testing in Google Chrome:_ **F12 > Settings (bottom right) > Overrides > User Agent > iPhone**

Comment: Yes thanks for your time... I'll keep looking... Gave you +1 for the time spent ;)

Comment: Thanks I tried that and it still redirects my /path/ pages... :(  I tried again to copy/past your entire code in a clean .htaccess file and it doesn't work... I also tried to restart Apache... Maybe there's something wrong with the server configuration?

Comment: Of course I have, otherwise the redirection would not work. The problem is that I want to avoid the redirection for /path/

Comment: You won't believe I finally made it work!!! I have no idea why, but the following works: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/path/.*$` – If I remove the `.*` at the beginning it won't work! I will update your answer so I can accept it ;) Cheers!

Comment: No no `/path/` is the start, I'm not that stupid ;) `http://www.example.com/path/` !!!

Comment: thanks so much! your solution worked perfectly for me :D

my RewriteCond too, for some reason, worked only with `^.*` appended at the starting of path