# Redirecting mobile users away from individual webpages pages to condensed webpage

Tags: php, .htaccess, mobile, responsive-design

First off I'm designing a responsive website, based around 3 sizes taking into account mobile, tablet and desktop. The tablet and desktop are almost identical as I’ve set the tablet design to shrink down slightly from the desktop version.

The website will be using a fluid grid system to allow for the responsive design, while also using PHP includes for header, footer and sidebar.

The problem is, I want to minimalize content and information for mobile devices, to do this I want to stop the user being able to access the individual service pages and re-direct them to a different page that condenses all of the information from the indervidual webpages into one webpage.

My Question is how would I approach this? for some reason I seem to think it can be done by .htaccess, although I'm not sure how, has anyone else run into this sort of thing before? are there any other methods to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess should be able to do the trick have a look at: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond. It would require checking the browser agent unless you have a mobile specific url setup. It would be done something like this.

```
...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} *user agent to redirect*
RewriteCond %{URL} *url to redirect from*
RewriteRule specificpage general page
...
```

Both the user agent and url are considered regexp. I don't know any other way besides javascript on the page. Also the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess) may be helpful.