# i used mobile website & create subdomain but not worked in mobile this is my .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, jquery-mobile

This is my auto generated htaccess file

> RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.rgaads\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.m\.rgaads\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "m\.rgaads\.com\/index\.html" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: your solution is incomplete, see that
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `DirectoryIndex` to avoid above rule:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

PS: You need to put `http://` in target URL or use target without domain name if used in same host:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?m\.rgaads\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks for reply 
I used it but not action just try it in ur mobile (m.rgaads.com)

Comment: what is DirectoryIndex and how it use

Comment: Just add `DirectoryIndex index.html` line in your .htaccess or Apache config. For info on DirectoryIndex you can search Google.

Comment: search in google- i could a line i.e. RewriteRule ^/?$ "http://m.rgaads.com/DirectoryIndex index.html" [R=301,L] this is right or wrong