# Direct ALL traffic (desktop, tablet and mobile) to mobile version from plugin in htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm looking to direct all traffic (desktop, tablet and mobile) to a site to the mobile version which is created with a wordpress plugin.

I'm really not sure what to add to the htaccess file to accomplish this.

I would appreciate anyones input.

Thanks :)

Comment: What's the name of the mobile site? Is there a cookie that the wordpress plugin uses?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do this in the .htaccess file can be done, but you must note that this relies on identifying the visitor's user agent. Therefore, you will need to create a set of rules to check against each visitor on each page load to ensure that they are redirected to the mobile site.

Upon writing this description, I thought of maybe just checking for desktop browsers and redirecting them to a desktop experience as there are a lot less desktop user agents than mobile. Regardless of what path you take (whether to redirect desktop or mobile), you will need to create the .htaccess rules.

You can find a [StackOverflow post explaining this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess).

**Note**: it will be important that you find a way to immediately label a user as an already redirected client so that you don't continuously check their user agent. This can be done by using a cookie. It is also explained in the linked question.