# how to redirect from mobile site to full site with .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mobile

Below is my .htaccess file that i got from 
[Mobile Redirect using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess)

```
# Check if mobile=1 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=1(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# Check if mobile=0 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 0
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# cookie can't be set and read in the same request so check
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]

# Check if this looks like a mobile device
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$

# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie}        !\mobile=0(;|$)
# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^ http://m.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Using this will redirect to m.domain.com like i was hoping.

My issue is with redirecting user back to the full site.

Can someone please explain to me how i can accomplish this.

Thank you

Edit*

Full .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess
# Check if mobile=1 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=1(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# Check if mobile=0 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 0
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# cookie can't be set and read in the same request so check
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]

# Check if this looks like a mobile device
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$

# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie}        !\mobile=0(;|$)
# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^ http://m.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: When should user be redirected back to full site from mobile site?

Comment: I wanted to add a button for user to go back to full site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your link as: `http://m.domain.com/some-link?mobile=0`

#### Full .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess
# Check if mobile=1 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=1(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# Check if mobile=0 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 0
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# cookie can't be set and read in the same request so check
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]

# Check if this looks like a mobile device
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^mobile=0(?:&|$)
# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie}        !\mobile=0(;|$)
# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^ http://m.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# Go back to full site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)mobile=0(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: You need to place it just below `RewriteBase /` line.

Comment: i have it now exactly how you stated above and when i go to the link i still get the mobile site

Comment: ok another thought can you place it just after `RewriteRule ^ http://m.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]` line. Also what is full link now to go back to full site?

Comment: And this you're doing from a mobile browser?

Comment: my only issue is once you go from mobile site to full site i can not get back to the mobile site unless i exit out of my browser and restart new browser. ex im at m.domain.com then i click go to full site. it will go to full site but then i put in url domain.com and i am not redirected unless i exit safari on iphone and end browser task and restart safari

Comment: It is awfully late here and I was just about to sign-off. So after this comment I won't be able to follow up but to go back to mobile site you need to put `?mobile=1` in your links.