# Mobile Redirect using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

My site is:
example.com

My mobile version:
m.example.com

Profile page is
example.com/profile or m.example.com/profile

Or posting page
example.com/posts or m.example.com/posts

Mobile version's url is similar. So, how to redirect the same page?
For example: user go (from facebook) into example.com/posts but he uses mobile device,
so how to redirect via .htaccess to m.example.com/posts

I saw this one [threat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess), but i'm confuse to create right rules.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent), except that you want to redirect the user. First you need a list of mobile user-agents. I am not going to suggest a list, but I think you should be able to find a list that is suitable for you.

Next, you want to go to your .htaccess file and add something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(user-agent1|user-agent2|user-agent3|etc)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

The first `RewriteCond` contains all user-agents you want to redirect. Remember that it is a regex, so you have to escape any special characters! The second `RewriteCond` checks if the host isn't already `m.example.com`. If we wouldn't check for this, we would create an infinite loop, redirecting to the same url over and over. The `RewriteRule` itself matches everything after the hostname (and before the query string) and redirects it to the mobile site. `$1` gets replaced with the first capture group in the regex in the first argument of `RewriteRule`. The `[R]` flag is not necessary in this case (links with `http://` will always be redirected), but it let's Apache know that it should do an external temporary redirect to the new url. The `[L]` flag will stop processing more rules if this rule matches.

See [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for more information.