# URL images rewrite rule .htacces for mobile

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a website called

www.website.com

I have a mobile website called

m.website.com (m is a subdomanin of website.com)

I have done the redirect to mobile with the help of @tim-stone answer from here:
[Mobile Redirect using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess/24036484#24036484)

I want to use an htaccess rule to rewrite pics url because now the pics url are like this:

m.website.com/pics/thumb/pic.jpg and are not visible from mobile device.

So how can I add an exception in .htaccess to not rewrite all the urls that are like:
www.website.com/pics/* in the www.website.com .htaccess file OR a rule to rewrite all 
m.website.com/pics/* to www.website.com/pics/* in the m.website.com .htaccess file (so the pics will pe visible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a `RewriteCond` before the `RewriteRule` that does rewrite the URLS, and exclude the image extensions. This is what I use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)
```