# How to redirect url to mobile version using htacces

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mobile

Sir, my website's mobile version is `www.m.example.com` I put the code of mobile site in folder named `mobile` .Now I want to redirect the mobile users to www.m.example.com. 
I put some code in htacces file and checked using mobile. Then www.example.com correctly redirected to www.m.example.com. But a problem found. The problem is that, when checked url with get variable like, `www.example.com/listing/category/ct-12` etc, it is redirected to only `www.m.example.com`. not to `www.m.example.com/listing/category/ct-12` . Anyone help me for correct htacces code..
My website is using PHP

This is My htacces code in public html

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ listing/list-name.php?State=$1&Location=$2&Name=$3&Id=$4 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ct-([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)$ listing/list.php?State=$1&Dis=$2&Loc=$3&Category=$4&CId=$5&start_page=$6 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ct-([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)$ listing/list.php?State=$1&Dis=$2&Category=$3&CId=$4&start_page=$5 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ct-([0-9]+)$ listing/list.php?State=$1&Dis=$2&Loc=$3&Category=$4&CId=$5 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/ct-([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)$ listing/list.php?State=$1&Category=$2&CId=$3&start_page=$4 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ct-([0-9]+)$ listing/list.php?State=$1&Dis=$2&Category=$3&CId=$4 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/ct-([0-9]+)$ listing/list.php?State=$1&Category=$2&CId=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^http://www.example.com index.php

Options -Indexes
```

This is my htacces in folder named `listing`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
Options -Indexes
```

My final htacces

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

# Check if this is the noredirect query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)noredirect=true(&|$)
# Set a cookie, and skip the next rule
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:0:%{HTTP_HOST},S]

# Check if this looks like a mobile device
# (You could add another [OR] to the second one and add in what you
#  had to check, but I believe most mobile devices should send at
#  least one of these headers)
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$
# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie}        !\smredir=0(;|$)
# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^ http://www.m.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ listing/list-name.php?State=$1&Location=$2&Name=$3&Id=$4 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ct-([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)$ listing/list.php?State=$1&Dis=$2&Loc=$3&Category=$4&CId=$5&start_page=$6 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ct-([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)$ listing/list.php?State=$1&Dis=$2&Category=$3&CId=$4&start_page=$5 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ct-([0-9]+)$ listing/list.php?State=$1&Dis=$2&Loc=$3&Category=$4&CId=$5 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/ct-([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)$ listing/list.php?State=$1&Category=$2&CId=$3&start_page=$4 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ct-([0-9]+)$ listing/list.php?State=$1&Dis=$2&Category=$3&CId=$4 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/ct-([0-9]+)$ listing/list.php?State=$1&Category=$2&CId=$3 [L,NC,QSA]



RewriteRule ^http://www.example.com index.php




Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Then provide your `.htaccess` contents

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess

Comment: We can investigate only after looking at your redirection rule.

Comment: But I don't see any rules here redirecting mobile users to `www.m.example.com`

Comment: @anubhava sir if you can, please suggest me a rule..

Comment: There is already a suggested rule in the linked question by MateuszOdelga

Comment: @anubhava K sir, i will check then inform if any error...

Comment: Good luck, try it out and let us know if you run into any trouble.

Comment: @anubhava Sir it is not working

Comment: Can you edit question and post the rule that you've tried and not working for you.

Comment: You need redirect rule based on `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}` actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this rule right below `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge\ |maemo|midp|mmp|opera\ m(ob|in)i|palm(\ os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows\ (ce|phone)|xda|xiino [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a\ wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r\ |s\ )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1\ u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp(\ i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-|\ |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac(\ |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt(\ |\/)|klon|kpt\ |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg(\ g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-|\ |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v\ )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v\ )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-|\ )|webc|whit|wi(g\ |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://m.website.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```