# Using Mod-rewrite to serve mobile versions of a page

Tags: http, mod-rewrite

I'd like to use Mod-rewrite to serve different versions of my page to different devices.  For example, I would send a different version to a device with a 1920 x 1024 monitor than I would to an iPhone. It seems like I want to have Mod-rewrite make its decision based on the content of HTTP_USER_AGENT and I'm wondering who is keeping track of what an iPad Air 2 puts in that variable, what an iPhone 6 puts, etc., etc., etc.  There must be a huge table somewhere that's up to date.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What's in a User-Agent?

It's not the device but the browsing software being used on it that reports its `HTTP_USER_AGENT` to a web server. In addition to the browser's name and version information, it typically includes the platform or device name as well as the OS version its currently running on.

For example, the latest Firefox 36 reports the following *user-agent*

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0
```

which includes its version `36.0`, the platform it's running on `Windows` and the OS version `6.3` i.e. Windows 8.1. The browsers usually also report if the system is 64-bit `WOW64`and the user's locale, although the default `en-US` is often missing.

Here's what Safari reports on Windows 7 and an iPad:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; fr-FR) AppleWebKit/533.20.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.4 Safari/533.20.27
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d Safari/8536.25
```

And, that's pretty much it. You won't receive detailed information like the device generation (is it an iPad 2?) or its display metrics (the resolution the screen is running on).

So, while you can determine the class of the device (desktop or mobile) and serve alternate content, you can't serve resolution-specific content. So, how does other websites do it? Well, the answer is..

#### HTML5

HTML5 lets you write dynamic layouts that adjust to the available screen real estate automatically. So, while on a desktop it would render your site in a 3x2 layout, it can automatically switch to 1x6 one on a mobile browser. The best part is that it works independent of the *user-agent*; so you'll see it auto-adjust the layout on a desktop browser too (when you resize it) as well as work on a mobile browser with its *desktop-mode* on where it purposely reports a different *user-agent* to receive the desktop version of your site.

#### User-Agent Repositories

But, *user-agent*s still do come handy. There's no standardized repository as such but there are plenty of sites that keep track of *user-agent* strings like [user-agents.org](http://www.user-agents.org/), [httpuseragent.org](http://www.httpuseragent.org/), [useragentstring.com](http://useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) etc. The last one has been kept the most up to date.

You obviously can't match all of them so would do a sub-string match instead like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (ipad|iphone|ipod|mobile|android|blackberry|palmos|webos) [NC]
```

Take a look at [Mobile Redirect using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess) for the different *user-agents* other have been using for their .htaccess(s) successfully.

---

#### Using JavaScript

I remember couple of years ago when I used to visit Google Search, it would profile my browser and redirect to itself with the display resolution attached to the query string. I believe they did it for analytics rather than the layouts. Now they encode everything (even their cookies) so you can't exactly tell what they're making a note of.

If you're interested in something similar, JavaScript can help you with that: `window.screen.width` and `window.screen.height` will give you the client's resolution. If you're only interested in the actual screen space the browser has to render your site, use `availWidth` and `availHeight` instead.

So, your `<script>` could redirect to resolution specific pages as

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  if ((screen.width >= 1280) && (screen.height >= 720)) {
    window.location.replace('http://example.com/index-hi.html');
  } else if ((screen.width >= 1024) && (screen.height >= 600)) {
    window.location.replace('http://example.com/index-med.html');
  } else {
    window.location.replace('http://example.com/index-low.html');
  }
</script>
```

Or, you could set a *cookie* and serve pages from a resolution specific directory using *.htaccess*.

Comment: Thanks Ravi for the excellent answer!  I'm aware of HTML's "Responsive Web Design" features but I'm hoping to do even better by having three versions of the site: full, tablet,  and smart phone. The website builder I use, Zackel, (see zackelwebsites.com) makes it trivial to resize and move things around to create a new version of the site (I'm talking "minutes"). I just need to know how much real estate I have so I can use a font size that's readable everywhere without a finger spread, doing whatever resizing and moving that requires. Your references should help me get that info. Thanks again!

Comment: Fantastic!  Many thanks, Ravi.  It's interesting how you can post a question to SO that gets no response at all for days and then adding a bonus brings a response that's off the charts for quality and thoroughness.