# Replace word in URL before redirect to mobile with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to know how can I replace a word in URL when redirect from desktop to mobile, redirection is realized with htaccess.

For example http://www.example.com/reportage/2000
change to            m.example.com/post/2000

This is my htaccess code for redirection.

```
RewriteRule ^admin($|/) - [L]

# Check if this is the noredirect query string
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
# Set a cookie, and skip the next rule
#RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:0:www.example.com]

# Check if mobile=1 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=1(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# Check if mobile=0 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 0
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# cookie can't be set and read in the same request so check
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]

# Check if this looks like a mobile device
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$

# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie}        !\mobile=0(;|$)
# Now redirect to the mobile site
#Redirect 301 ^/photoreportage /post
RewriteRule ^ http://m.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mobile Redirect using htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, cause I need to change the word in url before redirection, what is the point.

Comment: You can achieve that with url rewrite, please go through the examples once..

Comment: Dear Akhil, can you provide me example of the code, I can't still find anything appropriate to my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
RewriteRule ^reportage/(.+)$   http://m.example.com/post/$1   [L]
```

Note : I haven't tested the above,if you find it not working, feel free to comment

For changing :

```
www.mysite.com/en/photoreportage/5000
```

To :

```
m.mysite.com/en/post/5000
```

try :

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m.example.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
    RewriteRule ^photoreportage/(.+)$   http://m.example.com/en/post/$1   [L]
```

Comment: Thanks @Akhil, but if my url is like this, www.mysite.com/en/photoreportage/5000 and I nedd it to be m.mysite.com/en/post/5000. In this case what should I do?

Comment: refer to the example i have give, try to understand what i am doing, modify it according to your needs

Comment: I'm new in this, that's why I'm asking, ok I'll try to figure out.Thanks

Comment: I have access only to files

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^photoreportage/(.+)$   m.example.com/en/post/$1   [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$

# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie}        !\mobile=0(;|$)
RewriteRule ^ http://m.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]