# New Site not Showing in Mobile View

Tags: php, css, wordpress, mobile, responsive-design

I just relaunched a website from HTML to a responsive Wordpress site & theme. It's great on desktop, but folks who have visited via mobile before the relaunch are still seeing the old site.

Here is the website in question: http://www.marctech2.com

Here is what Googlebot & returning visitors see: [old website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH1AZ.png)(screenshot)

I have inserted viewport code (in both meta & css)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

@viewport{
    zoom: 1.0;
    width: extend-to-zoom;
}

@-ms-viewport{
    width: extend-to-zoom;
    zoom: 1.0;
}
```

I have also submitted the site to Google crawl, and submitted the sitemap via Google webmaster tools.

Is there code I can insert that will instruct mobile viewers to automatically clear their cache?

My clients don't want to announce their new site because returning visitors might see the old one, and I mean, they have a point: We don't know who's been there or not, and even if we did, what are we going to do? Email instructions on clearing caches to the world? Customers don't read technical emails, and even if they did, it looks unprofessional.

Comment: Can you include screenshots of how it looks, because I'm not convinced I'm seeing what you think I'm seeing.

Comment: screenshot of old site that is showing for returning visitors: http://i.stack.imgur.com/oH1AZ.png

Comment: I don't have a solution for you - but I'm not a returning visitor and I'm still seeing the old version of your mobile site.

Comment: What he said. I'm pretty sure I never visited your site before, but it does look like that on my phone.

Comment: wow. ok, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a cache issue. The old mobile site is still published.

If I were to bet, I'd put my money on something to do with your .htaccess file.

Comment: Really? Nuts. I'd never think to look at the .htaccess file for that. I'll check it out.

Comment: Couple things you can try... first remove the .htaccess file entirely.. Just rename it OLD.htaccess then attempt to refresh the site.

Review [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess) post about how to use htaccess to redirect to a mobile page. See if your htaccess looks similar.

Comment: holy mamajama, there's a BOATLOAD of mobile rewrites in there! GOOD GOD. I've removed it all.

Comment: DUDE, YOU ARE A FRICKING MASTER. Thank you so much, according to Google Pagespeed Insights, it's displaying properly now.