# Redirect one specific Wordpress URL to another site for mobile users in htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Need some syntax help if someone would be so kind. I have one page on my Wordpress site (http://www.thisweekonmv.com/vineyard-map) that I need to redirect to another website's URL for **mobile users only**. I would like to do this in .htaccess, but so far all of the solutions I've researched online haven't worked.

This is what I have that isn't working...I probably am close but something is definitely wrong?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|operamobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [nc]
rewriterule ^vineyard-map(.*)$ http://myatlascms.com/map/?id=938$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Refer this links**

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-redirect-links-for-mobile-using-htaccess

[Mobile Redirect using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess)