# Htaccess redirection all while hiding directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want visitors who are landing on `domain.com` from their desktop to be transferred to `domain.com/desktop`, all while hiding the "`desktop`" part in the URL.

Lastly, if they visit `domain.com` from their mobile, I want them to be  transferred to `domain.com/m`. In this case the "m" can stay I guess, I don't care.

My question is; is the redirection in the .htaccess or in the index.php of my public_html?

**EDIT :** My /desktop/ directory's htaccess contains this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^inc/.*$ index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

The root's `.htaccess` contains this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule !^desktop/ /desktop%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]
```

And my public_html's `index.php` contains :

```
include 'mobile_detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();
if ($detect->isMobile()) {
    header("Location: http://domain.com/m"); exit;
}else{
    header("Location: http://domain.com/desktop"); exit;
}
```

I feel like I'm doing something very wrong, I just can't figure out what it is. Help?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this duplicate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3796954/1476989) - it will redirect mobile users to `m.domain.com`, which could be a better system as you could use another VirtualHost to entirely separate the mobile website so it wouldn't cause any redirect loops.

As for the redirect to `/desktop`, why is that necessary? You could simplify this to two VirtualHosts:

*(VirtualHost config is normally stored in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`)*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName m.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mobile/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/desktop/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Note that I didn't test if the mobile redirection in the duplicate answer worked. If it doesn't, let me know and try this one instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34388377/1476989 (it's more recent)

Comment: Hey thank you very much for your suggestion! I will try this right away.