# Redirecting http://www.example.com to www.m.example.com using .htaccess

Tags: windows

I have a subdomain (m.example.in) for my mobile version of my site

how to Redirecting example.into m.example.in

Comment: Did you check the below answer?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess

Comment: I have a mobile website in a sub domain. Can I able to use that domain or I want to create a new domain for mobile website

Comment: how to redirect www.domain.com/mobile to www.m.domain.com