# htaccess - issue when trying to redirecting to mobile website (on subdomain)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am having some issue with the .htaccess file on one of my sites.

The error I get is that I'm trying to redirecting too many times.

The way it currently works is that I need to redirect the URL to the subfolder `/dist` everytime I'm on desktop, and if I'm on mobile, I need to go to the mobile version of the website instead which is a subdomain starting with `mobile.`

my htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Check if this is the noredirect query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=0(&|$)

# Set a cookie, and skip the next rule
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:0:www.mywebsite.com/dist]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.mywebsite\.com\/dist" [R=301,L]

# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.

# Can not read and write cookie in the same request, must duplicate condition
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)m=0(&|$)

# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}        !^.*mredir=0.*$ [NC]

# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^ http://mobile.mywebsite.com [R,L]
```

can anybody help?

this is my first attempt at something like this

thanks

Comment: Would help if you post error messages as well.

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Does your mobile site start with `m.` or `mobile.` ?

Comment: I have setup both m. and mobile.

Comment: Try your conditions as `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^(m|mobile)\.` [NC]`

Comment: I am probably doing something wrong..it now redirect every time (also on desktop)

can you write this as an answer with the full code updated? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Check if this is the noredirect query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=0(&|$)    
# Set a cookie, and skip the next rule
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:0:www.mywebsite.com/dist]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.mywebsite.com/dist [R=301,L]

# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(m|mobile)\. [NC]    
# Can not read and write cookie in the same request, must duplicate condition
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)m=0(&|$) [NC]    
# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*mredir=0 [NC]
# check mobile agents
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone|android" [NC] 
# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^ http://mobile.mywebsite.com [R=302,NE,L]
```

Comment: nope, it redirect everytime to the mobile version even if i am on desktop

Comment: For that you need to check user agent and that check wasn't present in your question.

Comment: well, according to this answer that check should work for mobile devices:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess any idea why it's not in my case?
thanks for your help so far, BTW :)

Comment: But that answer is using `%{HTTP:x-wap-profile}` and `%{HTTP:Profile}` headers to detect mobile device. You can try that instead of `HTTP_USER_AGENT` conditions I suggested above.