# How will i redirect the Mobile users to my amp page from wordpress for that single page?

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

I have manually coded my AMP HTML file and deployed in AWS S3 Bucket. The Canonical(Desktop version) of that page is in Wordpress. How will i redirect the Mobile users to my amp page from wordpress for that single page?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. You should be more specific about your needs.

Comment: You may try redirecting for mobile through the site's main `.htaccess` file. This link has a few options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

To redirect using codes a specific page you would use the `.htaccess` method, modifying the `.htaccess` file.
Here is an example:

```
Redirect /path/to/old/file/old.html /path/to/new/file/new.html
```

However since you are using WordPress there are easier ways to do that and the most often used method on WordPress is to use an SEO plugin such as Rank Math.