# My site keeps redirecting iPhone (Safari) users to other IP, results in a timeout

Tags: ios, iphone, web, redirect, timeout

I coded a simple landing page. Problem is, I added no additional lines of code but it keeps redirecting iPhone users to an IP/site I don't know... Tried browserstack's app to see if it was only that phone, but it's the same behaviour. So I'm afraid it being something malicious server-side.

My site is [somosbravery.com](https://www.somosbravery.com)

The problem occurs only in iPhone (already tested in PC and and Android phone).

Any clue...? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr - Your website was hacked

Just tested on an iPhone, somosbravery.com redirected to IP address 194.6.233.7, which is in a range assigned to a company in Ukraine, ukrmir.com.ua.

There is no response from that IP address.

Info from [ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io/AS33927).

Testing on desktop with small window (375 x 667), the redirected URL is:

```
http://194.6.233.7/mxjbb.cgi?default
```

There is a posting in [support.google.com](https://support.google.com/webmasters/forum/AAAA2Jdx3sUubrVYnNLK2M) that discusses a website problem with the same redirected URL.

Entering `https://somosbravery.com` into the file viewr at [aw-snap.info](https://aw-snap.info/file-viewer/) produces:

> Header returned by request for: https://somosbravery.com/ ->
>   66.147.244.230
>
> HTTP/2 302 server: nginx/1.16.1 date: Fri, 10 Apr 2020 23:15:20 GMT
>   content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 content-length: 287
>   location: http://194.6.233.7/mxjbb.cgi?default Note: This line has
>   redirected the request to http://194.6.233.7/mxjbb.cgi?default

So there must be a redirect on the server.

[This page dated May 4, 2015](https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/05/hacked-websites-redirect-to-bitcoin-org.html) describes a .htaccess file hack that redirects to http://194.6.233.7/mxjbb.cgi?default, the exact same redirect target as in this case.

Comment: thanks for the information, but how could this be possible... the only thing I wouldn't 100% trust is the cdn import in my css.
@import url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/helvetica-neue-9');

Comment: No idea, but I don't think is a DNS server problem. I accessed the same DNS router from the desktop, which worked fine. A http redirect in .htaccess? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess

Comment: It's not only iPhones, it also happens on desktop when the window is very small. Can you do a sitewide search for '194.6.233.7'?

Comment: Your .htaccess file is almost definitely hacked. Search for "mxjbb".

Comment: Thanks, completely forgot about that. Had no .htaccess in my site whatsoever anyway. I put in a default one and it's apparently dealt with now.