# Mobile detect directive only works after first refresh

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, caching, browser-cache

I am trying to detect mobile devices and send them to a different directory on my server. The desktop version of the website is a WordPress website; the mobile version is HTML. At the moment, the mobile website only loads if I refresh the page. The first load seems to come from the browser cache but this issue persists even after I clear the browser cache.

I am using this [Mobile-detect library](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) mobile detect library to detect if the device requesting the page is mobile and redirecting the visitor with PHP `header(Location: ...)`.

In the root of my server, I've got:

```
// website structure for mywebsite.com
/public_html 
    /lib
        /mobile-detect.php // the mobile detect 3rd-party library
    /m // the mobile website version
        /index.html
        /index.html.bak.bak
    /wp-admin
    /wp-content
        /themes/
            my-child-theme/
    /wp-includes
    etc...
```

Inside the header.php file in my child theme, I've tried the following:

```
<?PHP
    // at the top of the page
    require_once 'lib/mobile_detect.php';
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect;
    if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
        header('Location: https://mywebsite.com/m/');
        exit;
    }
?>
```

I tried expanding that with more directives related to caching:

```
<?PHP
    // at the top of the page
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); //from amclin

    require_once 'lib/mobile_detect.php';
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect;
    if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
        header('Location: https://mywebsite.com/m/');
        exit;
    }
?>
```

I've tried adding meta tags to the `<head>` of the document after the `PHP` code:

```
<meta http-equiv=“Expires” content=”-1″>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

And I've tried using Javascript in addition to all the rest of it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (screen.width <= 699) {
        document.location = "https://mywebsite.com/m/";
    }
</script>
```

The original example from the 3rd party mobile-detect library recommended using Cookies here but I have to admit, I didn't understand the logic of it. I tried it originally but had the same issue:

```
<?php
    @include('lib/mobile_detect.php');
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect();
    if ($detect->isMobile() && isset($_COOKIE['mobile'])) {
        $detect = false;
    }
    elseif ($detect->isMobile()) {
        header('Location:https://mywebsite.com/m/');
    } 
?>
```

The `index.html` page inside `public_html/m/` contains this:

```
<?php
setcookie('mobile','m',time()+3600,'/','mywebsite.com/');
echo @file_get_contents('index.html.bak.bak');
```

I also tried adding caching directives to this file:

I also tried using `wp_redirect` in place of `header()`:

```
<?PHP
    // at the top of the page
    require_once 'lib/mobile_detect.php';
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect;
    if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
        wp_redirect('Location: https://mywebsite.com/m/');
        exit;
    }
?>
```

The WP site uses Clearfy Caching plugin. I've cleared the cache on that time and again.

So I'm clearly working at the wrong level for this and am curious what's going on here.

Why is the browser getting the desktop version first and then, after refreshing the page, going to the server and getting a fresh header.php file? Is this code in the wrong place? Should it be in an index file somewhere else? Do I need to use cookies for this? Aggghhhh!

Thanks for your help on this!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered doing this at the server level via nginx server block or apache .htaccess? This way the request is process before it hits the application and therefore bypasses the desktop homepage issue your experiencing.

Apache : [Mobile Redirect using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess#answer-4208300)

Nginx : https://alvinalexander.com/technology/nginx-redirect-mobile-devices-users-mobile-website/

Comment: A neater solution would be to use an auto-prepend in the PHP config to run the current PHP detecton code before it gets anywhere near wordpress.