# how to redirect mobile user to mobile page

Tags: php, mobile

I created mobile site for existing webpage and in it, I placed the code in mobile folder
like **www.testing.com/mobile** and it works fine.

But what I need to do is if the user visited from mobile it should be redirected to mobile page and user visited from web it goes to default pages.

Here I used:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

to fit the page but url shows like **m.tesing.com** for mobile how to do this

By browser agent or any other ways. Thanks.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118581/redirect-mobile-devices-to-alternate-version-of-my-site) answer.

Comment: There is a lot of ways to do it, no one way is the best way.

Comment: Google is your friend: https://www.google.fr/search?q=php+detect+mobile&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:fr:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=-R5aU4X9JabR8gfq54CwCA

Comment: ya solved thanks for giving response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download this [detectmobile.js](https://github.com/miohtama/detectmobile.js) and make this changes in your head tag

```
 <head>
                <script src="detectmobile.js"></script>
                <script>
                        try {
                                // This is the URL where mobile
                                detectmobile.defaultMobileURL = "http://m.testing.com";
                                detectmobile.process();
                        } catch(e) {
                                // Make sure that in the fault modes
                                // we do not interrupt execution of other Javascript code
                        }
                </script>
        </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using jquery you can use simple javascript to detect it:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 window.location.replace("http://m.tesing.com");
 //or window.location = "http://m.tesing.com";
}
```

Or other technique with CSS

```
/* Smartphones ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  #some-element { display: none; }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {        
    if( $('#some-element').css('display')=='none' {
        window.location.replace("http://m.tesing.com");
     //or window.location = "http://m.tesing.com";    
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for detecting mobile devices and then redirect it

```
    <script language="javascript">
      if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) 
      {
        window.location = "http://m.domain.com";
      }
    </script>
```

The test() method has been used to test for a match in a string and if a match is found then a redirection takes place. Add this code at the top of the main index.php page.

Use this code on the mobile index.php to redirect back

```
    <script language="javascript">
      if( !/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) 
      {
        window.location = "http://testing.com";
      }
    </script>
```

As for the m.testing.com you will have to create an sub-domain.