# WURFL | PHP | Device ID not loaded in

Tags: php, mobile, wurfl

I am using WURFL to detect the device the user is connecting to the website with.
This way I can redirect users to a mobile friendly directory in my site, read here:
[Redirect mobile devices to alternate version of my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118581/redirect-mobile-devices-to-alternate-version-of-my-site)

I have downloaded WURFL and ran the example page. If I load the page using a desktop, it works fine. But if I try to run it on a mobile device (IOS 8), I get the following error:

```
Fatal Error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'There is no device with ID [apple_iphone_ver8] in the loaded WURFL data'
```

Below is the demo page given by WURFL:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>WURFL PHP API Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
// Include the configuration file
include_once './inc/wurfl_config_standard.php';

$wurflInfo = $wurflManager->getWURFLInfo();

if (isset($_GET['ua']) && trim($_GET['ua'])) {
    $ua = $_GET['ua'];
    $requestingDevice = $wurflManager->getDeviceForUserAgent($_GET['ua']);
} else {
    $ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    // This line detects the visiting device by looking at its HTTP Request ($_SERVER)
    $requestingDevice = $wurflManager->getDeviceForHttpRequest($_SERVER);
}
?>
    <h3>WURFL XML INFO</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><h4>VERSION: <?php echo $wurflInfo->version; ?> </h4></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content">
        User Agent: <b> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($ua); ?> </b>
        <ul>
            <li>ID: <?php echo $requestingDevice->id; ?> </li>
            <li>Brand Name: <?php echo $requestingDevice->getCapability('brand_name'); ?> </li>
            <li>Model Name: <?php echo $requestingDevice->getCapability('model_name'); ?> </li>
            <li>Marketing Name: <?php echo $requestingDevice->getCapability('marketing_name'); ?> </li>
            <li>Preferred Markup: <?php echo $requestingDevice->getCapability('preferred_markup'); ?> </li>
            <li>Resolution Width: <?php echo $requestingDevice->getCapability('resolution_width'); ?> </li>
            <li>Resolution Height: <?php echo $requestingDevice->getCapability('resolution_height'); ?> </li>
        </ul>
        <p><b>Query WURFL by providing the user agent:</b></p>
        <form method="get" action="index.php">
            <div>User Agent: <input type="text" name="ua" size="100" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['ua'])? htmlspecialchars($_GET['ua']): ''; ?>" />
            <input type="submit" /></div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to give write permissions to the folder, but this has not solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delete the the persistence directory and reload the wurfl.xml.  It sounds like it was not able to completely load the database.

Answer (score 0):

By default wurfl create cache folder. Move the cache folder of wurfl and load the database again.
I had same issue while  using laravel framework. I moved the cache and updated the composer and issue got resolved. It had updated its required xml file .